# Error when running ng serve Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular5, ng-bootstrap, elementref

I was running my angular 5 project with `ng serve`, then there is an error like this:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts(58,96):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(121,67):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(115,208):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.d.ts(12,45):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.d.ts(29,45):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.d.ts(37,44):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-window.d.ts(14,40):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.d.ts(11,27):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.d.ts(70,30):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts(9,27):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts(54,30):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts(94,30):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to reinstall the ng-bootstrap

you can uninstall the ng-bootstrap `npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
then install the ng-bootstrap `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0`

hope this help you, good luck.

Comment: Brilliant (thumbs up).. its working now, thank you for your help